# Laravel 5.5 get index key number after group by one field

Tags: php, laravel, indexing, key

I have a collection in Laravel, I use groupBy to grouping the collection by "location" field. But, it return the collection without index key number, I mean, when I'm using foreach($arrays as $key => $array), the $key return "location" value, I need it to return the index number like 0, 1, 2 just like the ordinary collection, anyone know how to do that?

```
Collection {#392 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "Chicago, Illinois" => Collection {#398 ▶}
    "New York City, New York" => Collection {#403 ▶}
  ]
}
```

it's have an index with the "location" value, this is because i use groupBy with location field. i need the index to be like this:

```
#items: array:11 [▼
        0 => array:28 [▶]
        1 => array:28 [▶]
        2 => array:28 [▶]
        3 => array:28 [▶]
        4 => array:28 [▶]
        5 => array:28 [▶]
        6 => array:28 [▶]
        7 => array:28 [▶]
        8 => array:28 [▶]
        9 => array:28 [▶]
```

Comment: show some code (query and php code)

Comment: okay, edited bro

Comment: we need your code (query) and your desire result. add query

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php)($collection). It returns the same array but with numeric keys. Or, for Laravel collection you can use method $collection->values().

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback and handle it by yourself:

```
$group_index = 0;
$grouped = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) use ($group_index) {
   $index = $group_index;
   $group_index++;
   return $index ;
});
```

As [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) suggest